# Maven - maven-war-plugin change destination directory (other than webapp)

Tags: java, spring, maven

I'm using springboot but I don't want it to copy my webapp folder during maven-war-plugin task because it contains a lot of files like bower_components folder. I'm using grunt so I'm adding another folder to my war.

```
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.6:war (default-war) @ saturne ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [saturne] in [D:\Workspaces\MyProject\trunk\target\saturne-1.0.0]
[INFO] Processing war project
...
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [D:\Workspaces\MyProject\trunk\src\main\webapp]
```

I tried a lot of things like excluding it in `<resources>` or like

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
        <webResources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                <exclude>**/*</exclude>
            </resource>
        </webResources>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I can't find a way to exclude it from resource copy.

Comment: The topic's title isn't quite good, I wanted to maven-war-plugin to copy another directory than webapp, and I found source directory option that solved the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not SpringBoot's fault, maven-war-plugins always copy webapp folder, so we changed it's source by our wanted source.

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <warSourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp-dist</warSourceDirectory>
     </configuration>
</plugin>
```