# Why aren't my jsp files displaying when deployed by Tomcat in war file?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jsp, tomcat

ANOTHER EDIT: I just re-read it and the question is very ambiguous: the problem is Tomcat won't show me the views. They ARE in a folder under Tomcat's webapps directory.

EDIT: BOUNTY available. The code is [here](https://gitlab.com/edmundday/swa-boot)

I have a spring boot web app that runs fine under eclipse tomcat server when I navigate to http://localhost:8080/swa-boot/.
 When I try to deploy it as a war under Tomcat 9.0.14 externally I get:

> Message /swa-boot/WEB-INF/views/home.jsp
>
> Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

`home.jsp` is in the `views` folder.

I have tried adding to pom the resource:

```
        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>**/**</include>
        </includes>
```

And the dependency

```
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
```

I have also tried removing the ‘provided’ scope.

I have in application.properties:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/views/ 
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

I have changed any `<a` tags in the jsp pages to be of the form:
`<a href=" <spring:url value="/mappedpath" /> ">TakeMeToTheController</a>`.

I have added the views folder to the Deployment Assembly.

The folders under tomcat web apps look like:
[image]

And under the tomcat server web apps directory:
[image]

Any ideas?

EDIT: Deployment Assemblies:
[image]

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43186315/tomcat-404-error-the-origin-server-did-not-find-a-current-representation-for-th

Comment: I have thanks. That is for problems running in Eclipse. Mine runs fine in Eclipse.

Comment: I know it's been a while since I've worked on projects that use .jsp files, but isn't it weird to store them in the `WEB-INF` directory in your project?  You can even see in the final project that they've been moved to the `WEB-INF/WEB-INF` directory.

Comment: Maybe! It is someone else's project I am just trying to make it BOOT-able.

Comment: @schoon, I agree with Powerlord it is weird to have jsp files under `WEB-INF`, usually they are all under `webapp` folder like `webapp/views/some.jsp`

Comment: @schoon, try my answer and if it not work give a try to move your JSP's to `webapp` folder

Comment: Why do you have `<warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>` in your war plugin ? Try removing it as your web resources are inside /src/main/webapp which is default web resource location. Beside that I dont see any issues. how are you building your war ? eclipse or  mvn from command line ?

Comment: To run: in Eclipse I do Maven - update project, then Maven install, then I copy the resulting war into the tomcat webapps folder.

Comment: can you try mvn clean install from command line from the project root ? Just to isolate if eclipse is building your project incorrectly. Check the m2 folder for your generated war.

Comment: @Veeram. Tried that no m2 folder but under target folder the war looks ok, same as before anyway, i.e. doesn't work.

Comment: Can you add the Deployment Assembly screenshot from eclipse ?

Comment: Done. I removed the broken one, and that did not help.

Comment: @schoon Please look at my answer. To resolve your main issue you have to get the war structure right. Once you have it and should resolve your jsps. As next steps you can then change web xml into java annotation config for spring boot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the generated war does not pick up contents of your src/main/webapp folder.

Change line no. 72 in your pom.xml as below 
`<warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>`

This way the generated war will have contents of src/main/webapp. Test the new war and see. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34652748/maven-maven-war-plugin-change-destination-directory-other-than-webapp) question to see how to correctly specify warSourceDirectory.

**Edit** 
In adition you need to remove the `web.xml` file from `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF` folder. Either delete it or move it outside src folder.

Next run an `mvn clean install` and deploy `target/swa-boot.war` to tomcat.

A working copy is here - https://storage.googleapis.com/schoon/swa-boot.zip

Comment: Thanks. Tried that: same error but `Message /swa-boot` only without the subfolders.

Comment: Can you write down the exact sequence of steps you follow starting with the way you run the maven job to the deployment?

Comment: Also I suspect the tags may not be loading properly. Comment out tag related references from your home.jsp and see. Lines 3,5,6 90 and if you are including copyright tag somewhere in home.jsp then comment out that as well.

Comment: To run: in Eclipse I do Maven - update project, then Maven install, then I copy the resulting war into the tomcat webapps folder.

Comment: Okay. The tags are not the issue. But you need to make 2 more changes in addition to change in pom.xml.                                                                                                                                                                                      1. Add the below line at the top of src/main/resources/application.properties  ````server.contextPath=/swa-boot````

Comment: 2. The presence of web.xml is causing an IllegalStateException resulting in a deployment failure in Tomcat. So remove the web.xml i.e. either delete it or move it outside the src folder.                                                                                       Now recompile and deploy. See what happens.

Comment: Yes deleted, no effect.

Comment: Well, that should not be the case. Because I used your same code base. Made the same changes and I am able to load the home.jsp from a tomcat. Infact, the change 2 (in application.properties) is not needed. Change in pom.xml and deleting the web.xml should be enough to load the home.jsp from within a tomcat version 9.0.16. Make sure you are making only the changes I mentioned. Completely delete the existing deployments from your tomcat and redeploy or may be deploy to a fresh tomcat instance. Because as I said, I made these same changes and I can see it working.

Comment: Interesting. I have tried different tomcats and different machines. Are you able to upload your code so I can try that? Maybe I have messed something up as I have made a bout 1 billion changes.

Comment: Started getting: `13-Feb-2019 13:31:34.963 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot initialize context because there is already a root application context present - check whether you have multiple ContextLoader* definitions in your web.xml!`

Comment: ````java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot initialize context because there is already a root application context present - check whether you have multiple ContextLoader* definitions in your web.xml!```` You are getting this because you have not removed the web.xml. You will see that if you unzip the war file. Delete the ````web.xml```` from ````src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/```` and run an ````mvn clean install```` and deploy the ````swa-boot.war```` file that gets generated inside ````target```` directory

Comment: Please confirm if this worked and if you have downloaded the zip file from the url i added in my answer. (I will delete it after you download to avoid storage costs). Also please accept this answer.

Comment: Yes it worked, did not need to download it in the end. Thansk again!

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like your config is incorrect:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

The file referenced - `servlet-context.xml` - does not exist under WEB-INF but under `src/main/resources` which means at runtime it will be under the root of the classpath and should therefore be referenced as below:

```
<param-value>classpath:/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
```

You can also remove this from your POM and delete the WebContent folder completely as the root of your web app, being a Maven project, is now webapp and not WebContent.

```
<warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
```

Comment: Good spot! Same problem though.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a couple of changes.

First change is to remove resources configuration. This is packing everything under /src/main/webapp into WEB-INF/classes with same source structure.

```
<resources>
   <resource>
    <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp</directory>
       <includes>
          <include>**/**</include>
       </includes>
   </resource>
   <resource>
    <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
   </resource>
   <resource>
    <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
      <includes>
         <include>**/**</include>
      </includes>
   </resource>
</resources>
```

Next change is to remove 
      `<warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>` from the war plugin. This is preventing from processing the web resources.

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
</plugin>
```

Next step is to run maven clean install and You should end up the below structure inside your war and spring would be able to locate your jsps correctly.

```
WEB-INF
   classes
      org
      META-INF
      static
      templates
   lib
   spring
   tags
   views
resources
```

**Update** - Finally was able to checkout your project. To run spring boot application as a traditional war inside a container you need to make few more changes.

Web.xml change to locate the app servlet correctly and remove the SpringBoot ServletIntializer and remove the import resources annotation.

That's all the changes.

Changes available in github - https://github.com/saagar2000/springboot-traditional

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks Veeram, but it was the `web.xml` that was the problem.

Comment: You are welcome. How does your war look like now ? Does it still have multiple web inf folder  ? Put the resources and war plugin as you have you will again see the same error. It is the package that is the main issue for page not found.

Comment: Yes it still has 2 WEB-INF. What should get rid of it?

Comment: Try my answer. It should get rid of multiple web inf and that is only changes you have to make. Remember the original error /WEB-INF/views/home.jsp not found. So after marking mentioned changes you will see your home jsp under that folder and everything should work as expected.

Comment: I have now added the tested code with screenshot and link to repo.